# Linking error in project : cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

This is the directory structure of my project:

```
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- libdashframework
|   |-- Buffer
|   |   |-- IMediaObjectBufferObserver.h
|   |   |-- MediaObjectBuffer.cpp
|   |   `-- MediaObjectBuffer.h
|   |-- Input
|   |   |-- DASHReceiver.cpp
|   |   |-- DASHReceiver.h
|   |   |-- IDASHReceiverObserver.h
|   |   `-- MediaObject.h
|   |-- MPD
|   |   |-- AbstractRepresentationStream.cpp
|   |   |-- AbstractRepresentationStream.h
|   |   |-- AdaptationSetStream.cpp
|   |   |-- AdaptationSetStream.h
|   |   |-- BaseUrlResolver.cpp
|   |   |-- BaseUrlResolver.h
|   |   |-- IRepresentationStream.h
|   |   |-- RepresentationStreamFactory.cpp
|   |   |-- RepresentationStreamFactory.h
|   |   |-- SegmentListStream.cpp
|   |   |-- SegmentListStream.h
|   |   |-- SegmentTemplateStream.cpp
|   |   |-- SegmentTemplateStream.h
|   |   |-- SingleMediaSegmentStream.cpp
|   |   |-- SingleMediaSegmentStream.h
|   |   |-- TimeResolver.cpp
|   |   `-- TimeResolver.h
|   `-- Portable
|       |-- MultiThreading.cpp
|       `-- MultiThreading.h
|-- libdash_test_automoc.cpp
|-- libdash_test.cpp
`-- Makefile
```

I am having a linking error in the project and can't figure out how to remove it.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
file(GLOB test_source RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        libdashframework/MPD/*.cpp
        libdashframework/Buffer/*.cpp
        libdashframework/Input/*.cpp
        libdashframework/Portable/*.cpp 
        libdash_test.cpp )

add_executable(libdash_test ${test_source})
target_link_libraries(libdash_test dash -lpthread)
```

Error:

```
Linking CXX executable libdash_test
CMakeFiles/libdash_test.dir/libdashframework/Buffer/MediaObjectBuffer.cpp.o: In function `libdash::framework::buffer::MediaObjectBuffer::SetEOS(bool)':
MediaObjectBuffer.cpp:(.text+0x55d): undefined reference to `libdash::framework::input::MediaObject::AbortDownload()'
CMakeFiles/libdash_test.dir/libdashframework/Input/DASHReceiver.cpp.o: In function `libdash::framework::input::DASHReceiver::GetNextSegment()':
DASHReceiver.cpp:(.text+0x48e): undefined reference to `libdash::framework::input::MediaObject::MediaObject(dash::mpd::ISegment*, dash::mpd::IRepresentation*)'
CMakeFiles/libdash_test.dir/libdashframework/Input/DASHReceiver.cpp.o: In function `libdash::framework::input::DASHReceiver::GetSegment(unsigned int)':
DASHReceiver.cpp:(.text+0x57f): undefined reference to `libdash::framework::input::MediaObject::MediaObject(dash::mpd::ISegment*, dash::mpd::IRepresentation*)'
CMakeFiles/libdash_test.dir/libdashframework/Input/DASHReceiver.cpp.o: In function `libdash::framework::input::DASHReceiver::GetInitSegment()':
DASHReceiver.cpp:(.text+0x615): undefined reference to `libdash::framework::input::MediaObject::MediaObject(dash::mpd::ISegment*, dash::mpd::IRepresentation*)'
CMakeFiles/libdash_test.dir/libdashframework/Input/DASHReceiver.cpp.o: In function `libdash::framework::input::DASHReceiver::DownloadInitSegment(dash::mpd::IRepresentation*)':
DASHReceiver.cpp:(.text+0x9b0): undefined reference to `libdash::framework::input::MediaObject::StartDownload()'
CMakeFiles/libdash_test.dir/libdashframework/Input/DASHReceiver.cpp.o: In function `libdash::framework::input::DASHReceiver::DoBuffering(void*)':
DASHReceiver.cpp:(.text+0xa84): undefined reference to `libdash::framework::input::MediaObject::StartDownload()'
DASHReceiver.cpp:(.text+0xab5): undefined reference to `libdash::framework::input::MediaObject::WaitFinished()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libdash_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/libdash_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I remove this linking error? 
After reading other similar questions, I have tried and changed the order of files in file() function. The order is similar to a working sample project so I think thats not the problem.

EDIT:

Although I had already linked the so file of libdash by putting it in the `/usr/bin` and `/usr/lib/` dir. But I also updated the cmake too. It still didn't help.

updated CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(libdash_test)


set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS")  


# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)


#libdash has to be manually installed 
set (DASH_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/include/libdash)
find_package(DASH REQUIRED)
link_directories(${DASH_LIBRARIES})

#set(LIBDASH_LIBRARIES "../build/bin" CACHE PATH "Path to libdash.so")
#set(LIBDASH_INCLUDES "../libdash/include/" CACHE PATH "Path to libdash includes")

file(GLOB test_source RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        libdashframework/MPD/*.cpp
        libdashframework/Buffer/*.cpp
        libdashframework/Input/*.cpp
        libdashframework/Portable/*.cpp 
        libdash_test.cpp )


add_executable(libdash_test ${test_source})
target_link_libraries(libdash_test DASH -ldash ${DASH_LIBRARIES} -lpthread)
```

Error in the current CMakeLists.txt (the one under EDIT):

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindDASH.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "DASH", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "DASH" with any of
  the following names:

    DASHConfig.cmake
    dash-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "DASH" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "DASH_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "DASH"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: You are missing to link so dash library. It's unrelated to the file command.

Comment: I already have pasted the libdash.so lib to /usr/lib/ld and /usr/bin if thats what you mean

Comment: You should build with make VERBOSE=1 and see how the linker is invoked exactly. Might reveal something obvious.

Comment: I dont know why `find_package(DASH REQUIRED)` isn't working. I mean I did setup the dir for it.

Comment: Maybe you need to set your LIBDASH_* vars before calling find_package(DASH)?

Comment: And clear your cmakecache.txt just in case

Comment: I tried that but that hasn't helped. Also, I dont know how to clear cmakecache. Most ques regarding that say there is no cache of cmake. I still did a `make clean` and reiterated the process . Nothing happened except for the error.

Comment: Well, the error message pretty much says it all. `find_package` requires either a find script or a config script to be present. CMake was unable to find either for `DASH`, so it aborted. Which either means you don't have the script, or you did not tell CMake where to find it. So first thing: Check if Dash provides a package script or a find script. If not, write one. Then make sure that file can be found from your build script.